# How to show a user disabled message to client when user is disabled in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using spring security for authentication of my app. I want to inform the client that its account is signed but not enabled yet. This is users configuration in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` :

```
@Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user1")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("1"))
                .authorities("ROLE_USER1")
                .and()
                .withUser("user2")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("1"))
                .authorities("ROLE_USER2")
                .disabled(true)
        ;
    }
```

My authorization config:

```
     @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/public").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/private1").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER1")
                    .antMatchers("/api/private2").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER2")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/loginNeeded").permitAll()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .failureForwardUrl("/login/failed")
                    .successForwardUrl("/login/succeed")
                    .and()
                    .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "account")
            ;

        }
```

`user2` is disabled. I know there is a `DisabledException` in spring security, but I can't get this exception when I try to login with disabled `user2`. It seems that Spring considers disabled user like any other login failed tries.

I'm using `postman` as client.

Can anyone help solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which exception in this case are you getting? is it `AuthenticationException `?

Comment: @procrastinator The problem is that I have no exception. It just goes to "/loginNeeded" url of loginpage() method. I set "/loginNeeded" url for returnning ResponseEntity with 401 status code. When I log in with disabled "user2", "/loginNeeded" will be triggered without any exception

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use AuthenticationFailureHandler(e.g. TokenAuthenticationFailureHandler etc) for Spring security for this case. 
This handler can be used to modify the error message for each case upon which you distinguish the type of error that occurred.